# Distribution of the sum of n independent variables of the exponential family.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Suppose you have $n$ random and independent variables $Y_{1},...,Y_{n}$ whose distribution belongs to the uniparametric exponential family.

How do I find the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} Yi$ ?

Comment: Suggest you use moment generating functions; the sum of $n$ iid exponential random variables is distributed as a gamma distribution with shape parameter $n.$ // Some Answers listed at the right under 'Related' may be helpful.

Comment: Hard to tell without being given the exact distribution of the $Y_i$'s.

Comment: @BruceET Question says "exponential family".

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_i \sim \exp(1)$, i.e. $f_Y(y) = e^{-y}$ and $F_y(y)=1-e^{-y}$. You can extend the analysis easily to $Y_i \sim \exp(\lambda)$.

Let's consider the case of $n=2$, i.e. $X = Y_1+Y_2$.

$F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$

= $P(Y_1+Y_2 \leq x)$

= $\int_0^x P(Y_1 \leq x-y) f_Y(y) dy$

= $\int_0^x \left( 1-e^{-(x-y)}\right) e^{-y} dy$

= $\int_0^x (e^{-y} - e^{-x})dy$

= $1-e^{-x}-xe^{-x}$

You can differentiate to get the PDF $f_X(x) = xe^{-x}$.

If you do this a couple more times, you will see a pattern, at which point you can arrive at the answer by the principle of mathematical induction. The moment generating function approach is of course much quicker, if you are familiar with that.

Comment: the question says "exponential family"